# Clear find results on every new find in Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text-3

Is there a way to clear results every time I do a new **Find** in Sublime Text (version 3 for this case)?

I dont want to have an history of what was searched before in the **Find results** tab.

Comment: This question is confusing. The title and first few lines allude to clearing the panel. Only the last few lines seem to be real intent of the question.

Comment: Are you worried that the history is being logged? Or do you just want the input area to be cleared so you can run a new search? After running a search I believe you can just hit the down arrow key to clear the text currently in the search input (assuming that text input box has focus).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a built in option to do so in the settings.
The only method I know to make Sublime 3 "forget" the searched last strings is to erase them from a session file that is created after closing Sublime.

So, below is the method to make Sublime 3 "forget" the last searched strings from a previous session:

1. Go to the `Local` folder of Sublime, which can be found in the app data folder.

   on Windows:

   ```
   %appdata%\Sublime Text 3\Local\
   ```

   On Linux:

   ```
   ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/
   ```

   On OSX:

   ```
   ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/
   ```

In this folder you will have a file called `Session.sublime_session`.

2. Edit the file with another editor (say Notepad++), and search for `find_history` string in it.
3. Erase the quoted value that found between the brackets (this should be your last search string)

For example,
If you have the following shown in the `Session.sublime_session` file:

```
"find_state":
{
    "case_sensitive": false,
    "find_history":
    [
        "previously_searched_string"
    ],
```

Then after the deletion it should look like this:

```
"find_state":
{
    "case_sensitive": false,
    "find_history":
    [
    ],
```

You can also write a script that will do so automatically after closing Sublime.

Hope it helps.

Comment: For OSX the file has moved and is now in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/

Answer (score 1):

You can just close the **Find results** tab. When you reopen it (using shift+ctrl+f), it will be empty.

Comment: the idea is to clear it without having to close the window